# Sum 2 columns together, update query

Tags: sql, sum

```
UPDATE tbl_users 
   SET cash = SUM(cash + (SELECT reward FROM tbl_missions WHERE id = 1)) 
 WHERE id = 1 
 LIMIT 1
```

This is my query. It doesn't work, and I couldn't find anything when I searched the web. How can I fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: does it work when you remove the SUM function? you would need the sum only when you have multiple rows.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're trying to do an update-join:

```
UPDATE `tbl_users` u
JOIN   (SELECT   id, SUM(`reward`) AS reward_total
        FROM     `tbl_missions` m
        GROUP BY id) ON u.id = m.id
SET    `cash` = `cash` + m.reward_total 
WHERE  `id` = 1
```

Comment: No i just try to do something like this var = var + var2; but then in SQL i tried your query but it doesn't work neither but thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't that just be:

```
UPDATE `tbl_users` 
SET `cash` = `cash` + (SELECT `reward` FROM `tbl_missions` WHERE `id` = 1)
WHERE `id` = 1 
LIMIT 1
```

... unless I'm missing something in your question, I think that's what you're looking for.

Comment: That is also what i tried.. but yeah that is what i want weird enough it doesn't work.. :(

Comment: Would be good to update your question with perhaps the relevant data rows from each table (or just the values of CASH and REWARD for rows ID = 1). Also, you should update the question and specify what DBMS you are using... Sql Server? Oracle? MySql? etc.